# excon gem dependency conflict between mandrill-api and fog. (Rails 3)

Tags: rubygems, dependencies, fog, mandrill, excon

In my gemfile I have

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'fog'
gem 'mandrill-api'
```

When I run `bundle` I receive this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon":
  In Gemfile:
    mandrill-api (>= 0) ruby depends on
      excon (~> 0.15.4) ruby

    fog (>= 0) ruby depends on
      excon (0.13.4)
```

I'm not sure how to deal with dependency conflicts like this other then searching for versions of the two conflicting gems which don't have the conflict. Obviously, I'd like to be able to use the versions I choose and not be limited by dependency conflicts. In this case, I'm not even sure if it is possible to find non-conflicting versions.

My question is, can you fix this error, preferably without specifying older versions of either of the two gems?

Let me know if you need any more info to answer the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had an older version of of `fog` specified previously. This had the older dependency on `excon`. I ran `bundle update fog` and the dependency problem was solved via the newly updated version of `fog`. I'd still like to know if you can specify different versions of gem dependencies but that should be a new stackoverflow question. I'll leave this question up, incase someone else runs into this same issue.